# Flow $ObjMap on type parameter

Tags: flowtype

Flow isn't producing the error I expect in the following.  Is it a bug with Flow (probably) or do I misunderstand something about type parameters?

```
function test<A: Object>(
  obj: A,
  mapper: $ObjMap<A, <V>(V) => V => any>
) {
}

test(
  {
    foo: 1,
    bar: '2',
  },
  {
    foo: (x: number) => String(x),
    bar: (x: number) => parseInt(x),
    //       ^^^^^^
    // should error that this is the wrong argument type
  }
)
```

It seems like a bug because the following produces an error, albeit in the wrong place:

```
const a = {foo: 1, bar: '2'}
type A = typeof a
type B = $ObjMap<A, <V>(V) => V => any>

const b: B = {
  foo: x => String(x),
  bar: (x: number) => parseInt(x),
}
```

Error:

```
3: type B = $ObjMap<A, <V>(V) => V => any>
            ^ Cannot instantiate `$ObjMap` because string [1] is incompatible with number [2] in the first argument.
   References:
   1: const a = {foo: 1, bar: '2'}
                              ^ [1]
   7:   bar: (x: number) => parseInt(x),
                 ^ [2]
```

Comment: I can't really say if this is a bug or not, but it appears to work if you do `mapper: $ReadOnly<$ObjMap<A, <V>(V) => V => any>>`

Comment: I haven't looked at this carefully, but note that `Object` is an unsafe type and is now just an alias for `any`. I recommend removing it and the `any` types, since they are designed to circumvent the type system. You are likely to get unsafe typechecking behavior when using these unsafe types.

Comment: @NatMote all of the mapper functions can have different return types though, so how can I require all values of `mapper` to be functions without constraining their return type?

Comment: Seems like I can actually do `$ObjMap<A, <V, R>(V) => V => R>`, but I'm not sure if it's really kosher

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I was able to get it to work with

```
declare function test<A: Object, M: $ReadOnly<$ObjMap<A, <I, O>(I) => I => O>>>(
  obj: A,
  mapper: M
): $ObjMap<M, <I, O>((I) => O) => O>
```

Not ideal because the output is only assignable to a `$ReadOnly` shape, but it covers all the type checking I need.